# Decode Multi-Layer HEVC

Tags: ffmpeg, hevc

I'm trying to decode an HEVC/H.265+ rtsp stream to an image using ffmpeg as follows:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -stimeout 10000000 -i 'rtsp://user:passwd@url:port/Streaming/tracks/101?starttime=20210826T130000Z&endtime=20210826T130010Z' -vframes 1 -y image.jpg
```

but I'm getting the following:

```
[rtsp @ 0x56031fe7f500] Multi-layer HEVC coding is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.

[rtsp @ 0x56031fe7f500] Multi-layer HEVC coding is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.

[rtsp @ 0x56031fe7f500] Multi-layer HEVC coding is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.

[rtsp @ 0x56031fe7f500] Multi-layer HEVC coding is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.

[rtsp @ 0x56031fe7f500] Multi-layer HEVC coding is not implemented. Update your FFmpeg version to the newest one from Git. If the problem still occurs, it means that your file has a feature which has not been implemented.
```

I tried using the latest version of ffmpeg but still the same issue.

Comment: I think FFMPEG logs had provided a pertinent answer; do you think so?

Comment: I tried using the latest version of ffmpeg but it still the same, when investigating deeply I found that the first frames are not decoded correctly but the next ones are decoded normally. If I reference [this paper](https://www.hikvision.com/content/dam/hikvision/en/brochures-download/product-brochures/White-Paper_H.265-Plus-Brochure.pdf), seems like ffmpeg is extracting just the residual part